# Exiting thread in a python multithreaded server

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make a multithreaded server in python right now that sends a header line and then the html file requested but I've run into a bit of a snag. I'm pretty sure my threads aren't exiting when the function is done. My server is printing "ready to serve..." more times than it should (and encountering random errors from time to time). I heard that if a thread hits a handled exception it might not exit, but it appears not to exit even when things run smoothly without exception.

I'm pretty new to python and am used to making these in C where I can simply exit threads from within the thread but my research has told me it's not quite that simple in python. Any help on how to fix or improve the server would be amazing!

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
import threading

def work(connectionSocket):
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send("Header Line")

        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send("404 File Not Found.")
        connectionSocket.close()

    return

def server():
    threads = []
    serverPort = 14009
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    #Prepare a sever socket
    serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(1)
    while True:
        #Establish the connection
        print 'Ready to serve...'
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(connectionSocket,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    serverSocket.close() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints out 'Ready to server' more than once is that you put `print 'Ready to serve...'` in the loop. If you only want it to print once, just put it outside the loop.

And to make sure that every thread exits, it's a better practice to join all the threads when the program ends. Then the code would be like this:

```
print('Ready to serve...')
while True:
    #Establish the connection
    try:
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(connectionSocket,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

print("Exiting")
for t in threads:
    t.join(5)
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I know i had "ready to serve..." in the loop but I was expecting it to print once more per request but it was printing twice or more after each request which lead me to believe the thread wasnt exiting and coming back to the loop where the main thread already was and looping simultaneously with it.

Comment: With your code i definitely dont get any errors anymore but it still prints ready to serve multiple times per request... Again, thank you!